# My profile pic only appears after I touch it on app load

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

I've created a social media app with Ionic 4, Firebase, Angular and it works fine on Android.  But on iOS, when I load the app my profile pic won't appear unless I actually touch it.

Here's the code

```js
  async ngOnInit() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log('onAuthStateChanged', user.uid);

      this.currentUser = user;
      this.imageService.getImageDownloadUrl( 'profilePicture', user.uid)
      .then((photo) => {
        console.log('getImageDownloadUrl', photo);

        this.profilePicture = (photo === 'undefined') ? 'false' : photo;
        console.log('profilePicture', this.profilePicture);
      });
    });
  }
```

```html
  <div class="profilePhoto" [ngSwitch]="profilePicture">
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <img [src]="profilePicture" (click)="Present('profilePicture')">
  </div>
  <div class="logo" *ngSwitchCase="'false'">
    <ion-img style="padding-top: 25px; " src="assets/image/SpaghettiPlus2.png" (click)="openImagePicker('profilePicture')"></ion-img>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have to touch the pic with Android, it just appears on load, but with iOS, it won't load the actual pic, it will just keep the default pic until I actually touch the pic then it magically appears.

Comment: Does the app show your default picture or none of both pictures before you tap it on iOS?
How do you test those platforms - emulator, build via xcode, ...?

Comment: When I upload a profile picture, it loads correctly in the app and in Firebase. Once I shut down the app and reopen it reverts back to my default picture.  This only happens in IOS. Android loads the profile pic stored in Firebase.

Comment: So you save your picture in firebase storage, aren't you? Have you set up Firebase Storage for iOS?
Maybe [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start) can help you

Comment: Yes, I have. And Everything is working correctly for Android.

Comment: Hm. I don't really know how to fix that. Often those iOS issues appear, because the enviroment is stricter following some standards (e.g. angular date pipe is not working with all date formats like in firefox) but it's hard to say in your example. Shall I have another idea I will comment again, otherwise good luck.

Comment: Have you tried to use *ngIf instead of ngSwitch? I suspect it could be the problem. Try something like this:
https://gist.github.com/hanibhat/652a672ca7cedea0bb92dc7d94b1b3be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try NgZone as i use below code may you get what you want

```
 constructor(ngZone: NgZone){ }

async ngOnInit() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    this.currentUser = user;
    this.imageService.getImageDownloadUrl('profilePicture', user.uid)
      .then((photo) => {
        console.log('getImageDownloadUrl', photo);

        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.profilePicture = (photo === 'undefined') ? 'false' : photo;
          console.log('profilePicture', this.profilePicture);
        }
          });
  });
}
```